# How to declare generic variable of MutableSharedFlow<EventFilter<T>>() in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I'm new in kotlin generic here I try to declare generic variable of   `MutableSharedFlow<EventFilter<T>>()`

I try this one but show error on `var <T>`

```
var <T> event = MutableSharedFlow<EventFilter<T>>()
     ^
     Error :Type parameter of a property must be used in its receiver type
```

I don't understand this error any one guide how to declare this one in generic way.

```
enum class EventType {
    DEFAULT,
    ADD_PLAY_LIST,
    PLAY_PAUSE,
    STOP
}


data class EventFilter<T>(var eventType: EventType = EventType.DEFAULT, var anyObject: T? = null)

var <T> events: MutableSharedFlow<EventFilter<T>> = MutableSharedFlow<EventFilter<T>>()

fun <T> receivedEventX(filter: EventFilter<T> = EventFilter(), onReceivedEvent: (event: EventFilter<T>) -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        events.collectLatest {
            onReceivedEvent.invoke(it)
        }
    }
}

fun <T> sendEventX(event: EventFilter<T> = EventFilter()) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        events.emit(event)
    }
}
```

Comment: By declaring a property as generic, you're saying you want its type to vary depending on how and where it's accessed. That doesn't make sense for a property like this one with a backing field. The value stored in it can't change its type: it will always be of whatever type you originally stored in it. Why do you want to declare this property as generic?

Comment: @Sam I edited my question I try to make like Event Bus to send and received messages in generic I can send any type of object.

Comment: A property has a value in it. That value can’t change based on what the caller asks for unless you use a custom getter that returns different objects each time it’s called. But the syntax for providing a type as an input to a property getter doesn’t exist. You would have to use a function instead of a property.

Answer (score 0):

To declare a `MutableSharedFlow` can use:

`val flow: MutableSharedFlow<EventFilter<T>> = MutableSharedFlow()`

with default type `Any?`.

and use it with a special type:

`val thisFlow: MutableSharedFlow<EventFilter<String>> = MutableSharedFlow()`